# How to pass arguments for slug with (routing) in laravel 8?

Tags: php, routes, slug, laravel-8

How to write this in Laravel 8 ? Please help .

```php
Route::get('blog/{slug}',
    [
        'as' => 'blog.single',
        'uses'=>'BlogController@'getSingle'
    ]
);
```

1. My controller

```php
class BlogController extends Controller
{
   
    public function getSingle($slug) {
        
        return $slug;
    }

}
```

Comment: `'BlogController@'getSingle'` there a extra quote.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

```php
class BlogPost extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

and then

```php
public function getSingle(\App\Model\BlogPost $post) {
    
    return $post;
}
```

```php
Route::get('blog/{post}', [BlogController::class, 'getSingle']);
```

Alternatively you can also use :

```php
Route::get('blog/{post:slug}', [BlogController::class, 'getSingle']);
```

second param is the name of the attribute used to find the post, then you don't need setup `getRouteKeyName`